# NET Core Class Library read file in a project folder

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a NET Core Class Library project that need to read file contents (template file) from a folder within the project. I am using Visual Studio Code

The files are stored as follows:

```
    --Application (root)
    ---Functions (library for functions)
    ---(c# classes)
    ---Services (library for services)
    ---(c# classes)
    ---Templates (templates)
    -----template1.txt
    -----template2.txt
    -----template3.txt
```

How can I do that? also, will be safe for other OS like Unix and OS?

Comment: You'd better embed those templates as resources. Once the source code is compiled, the binaries (including your class library) might be deployed in an arbitrary folder, from where no way can reliably go back to your source code folder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hopefully I understand your question correctly.

You can do something similar to:

```cs
using System.IO;

public class MyLocations
{
    public static readonly string App = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

    public static readonly string Templates = Path.Combine(App, "Templates");
}
```

and in your `Main` you could do something like:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  foreach ( var filePath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(MyLocations.Templates) )
  {
    var contents = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

    // do something with "contents"
  }
}
```

This should function properly on a Mac and Linux machine.